# Decompressing image size to a maximum size

Tags: image, editor, compression

I have a .png image. The file size is 200KB. My client is asking he needs the same .png file in a 20MB file size. Is there any way i can increase the file size to my desired size?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you'd need such a large image... But try converting it to a .TIF, it probably won't get you to 20MB, and you'd have to change types, but it's the best I can think of.

Comment: Yes sir. I've tried that but the client needs 20MB png file. I am also wondering why he needs that.

Comment: Try changing the images resolution... Max it out. Image size has to do with the amount of pixels that has to be "drawn" so to speak. Higher res = more pix = more volume in memory. Although, 20MB is huge for an image file. I don't think any resolution that can be placed will make it that large